# Hide class members outside namespace

Tags: c++

I have a collection of classes that have node like relationships. Due to this, I need to access some of the parents/chilren functions that I'd otherwise like to keep away from the end user since they just clutter the suggested method list, make no sense and break things really bad when used from outside their own "ecosystem".

I figured if they'd all inherit the same base class with virtual placeholder functions then I could access the protected members but apparently not. Is there a way to hide class members from access outside a certain namespace or a container class while being accessible from within?

Comment: Make them private and grant friendship as necessary, perhaps?

Comment: I consider it to be a big problem when your design choices are almost entirely influenced by what shows up in some IDE's "suggested method list". Sigh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have to has access to some protected/private data you can make friend classes.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class):

```
class B {
    friend class A; // A is a friend of B

private:
    int i;
};

class A {
public: 
    A(B& b) {
        b.i = 0; // legal access due to friendship
    }
};
```